# Changing the user running a Jenkins process

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, jenkins, ssh-keys

I wonder how to change the user starting a jenkins server on my ubuntu.

In `http://[server]:8080/systemInfo` page I can find an environment variable:
USER    jenkins

My motivation is to set to user 'git' to a turnaround a failure of jenkins to clone a git project hosted by the user 'git' on the same computer:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: 
Command "git clone --progress -o origin ssh://git@[server]:22/~/[repo].git /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/[project]" returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/[project]...
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

... after generating ssh keys for the jenkins user and verifying accurate settings in the SSH settings of Jenkins.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You talked about verifying the settings within Jenkins. But did you verify that if you `su` to the `jenkins` user you can then `ssh git@[server]` without a password?

Comment: Running the same git command than jenkins from console requires a password and works. When defining this password in the jenkins settings, it fails as printed above.

Comment: If it requires a password, then the keypair isn't set up properly. Try `chmod 700 ~jenkins/.ssh ; chmod 600 ~jenkins/id_rsa` on the jenkins server.

Comment: It might also be helpful for you to post output from `ssh -v git@[server]`.

Comment: Lastly, be sure the public key is property installed on the git side. It sounds like you've already done that, but it can't hurt to double-check.

Comment: Heeeyyy thanks :) `ssh myuser@server.com mkdir .ssh
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myuser@server.com:.ssh/authorized_keys` definitly fixed the problem :/ Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think changing the user that Jenkins is running under is the solution.

You should log into your Ubuntu box as the Jenkins user (or `sudo su - jenkins` to it) and then verify that `ssh git@[your-git-server]` works correctly. More than likely, there is a missing SSH key or a permission problem with one of files or directories related to the SSH key.

Either that or the `git` command-line tools don't recognize SSH keys configured from within Jenkins. I **know** they work when I have a `jenkins` user with a valid `~jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa` and a valid entry in `~jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: When calling   jenkins@[server]:~/.ssh$ ls   I got
id_rsa id_rsa.pub  known_hosts

Comment: Also, what does the following command print: `openssl rsa -inform pem -in ~jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa_test -check -noout`? (Does it ask for a password? Because if so, you might want to consider using an unencrypted RSA key, unless you want to deal with starting the Jenkins server by hand with an `ssh-agent` active every time.)

Comment: Correction: `openssl rsa -inform pem -in ~jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa -check -noout`. (must execute this as root or as the `jenkins` user)

Comment: when su as `jenkins` output is: `RSA key ok`

Comment: You may also need to check the permissions of your `~jenkins/.ssh` directory and its contents (and any directories along the path). Try `chmod 700 ~jenkins ~jenkins/.ssh` and then `chmod 600 ~jenkins/.ssh/*`.